# Most Efficient Way to Query a Table with Children, Grandchildren, etc

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table with a list of Jobs that have children, grandchildren, etc. There is no limit on the level of hierarchy it goes down. The table has ID, Name, and ParentID. So for example, a Job table could look like:

```
ID  Name               Parent ID
1   Education          null
2   IT                 null
3   Teacher            1
4   MS Teacher         3
5   7th Grade          4
6   Sys Admin          2
7   HS Teacher         3
8   12th Grade         7
9   IT Support         6
10  Developer          2
```

There is also a UserToJob table that is just the JobID and UserID. A person could be listed in more than one Job.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to get all people with a specified job and all decedents, so if I want to query for Education then it returns Education, Teacher, MS Teacher, 7th Grade, HS Teacher, and 12th Grade.

Right now my best attempt looks like

```
with 
Closure AS (
select j.ID as AncestorID, j.ID as DescendantID, 0 as Depth from Jobs j
UNION ALL
select CTE.AncestorID, j.ID, CTE.Depth + 1 from Jobs j
inner join Closure CTE on j.ParentID = CTE.DescendantID
),
Job AS ( select j.UserID as ID from UserToJob j
where j.JobID in (select DescendantID from Closure where AncestorID in (1))
)
```

I want it to be able to work querying more than one job at a time, for example if I wanted all Education and Sys Admins then I'd change `AncestorID in (1)` to `AncestorID in (1, 6)` in the final line of my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You have your where clause in the wrong place. You want to limit the root of your recursive cte to only return the first level rows you are concerned with.

This should point you in the right direction.

```
declare @Jobs table
(
    ID int
    , Name varchar(50)
    , ParentID int
)
insert @Jobs values
(1, 'Education', null)
, (2, 'IT', null)
, (3, 'Teacher', 1)
, (4, 'MS Teacher', 3)
, (5, '7th Grade', 4)
, (6, 'Sys Admin', 2)
, (7, 'HS Teacher', 3)
, (8, '12th Grade', 7)
, (9, 'IT Support', 6)
, (10, 'Developer', 2)

select *
from @Jobs;

with Closure AS 
(
    select j.ID as AncestorID
        , j.ID as DescendantID
        , 0 as Depth 
    from @Jobs j
    where j.ID in (1, 6)

    UNION ALL

    select CTE.AncestorID
        , j.ID
        , CTE.Depth + 1 
    from @Jobs j
    inner join Closure CTE on j.ParentID = CTE.DescendantID
)

select *
from Closure
```

Comment: My where clause is not in the wrong place, how it is right now works fine. What I am asking about however is efficiency, is it the best way to do things? Is your query more efficient than mine?

Comment: It would seem to be at least a little more efficient. You are pulling the entire Jobs table first and then dropping the rows that don't meat the criteria later. With the where clause in the root of the cte it doesn't do all the recursion to later ignore those rows. But you also have a table UserToJob in your cte stack that isn't in the question. The best way to determine the performance is to compare the execution plans of each approach.